# Add Request body Schema in loopback4

Tags: routes, openapi, strongloop, loopback4

I'm new with loopback 4 and I really have difficulty with the documentation that is some time not up to date. I succeed to add an authentification system and a route to log in to the users. My problem is on the "/explorer" URL, I don't know how can I add example value on the request body schema of a custom route.

There is my route:

```js
@post('/users/login', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Token',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                token: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  async login(
    @requestBody() credentials: Credentials,
  ): Promise<{token: string}> {
    // make sure user exist,password should be valid
    const user = await this.userService.verifyCredentials(credentials);
    // console.log(user);
    const userProfile = await this.userService.convertToUserProfile(user);
    // console.log(userProfile);

    const token = await this.jwtService.generateToken(userProfile);
    return Promise.resolve({token: token})
  }
```

And I wish to add:

```js
{
   "username": "string",
   "password": "string"
}
```

Here:
[image: /explorer url]

I suppose that there is a simple way to do it but I really can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI: The loopback4 uses the route Decorator, which provides OpenAPI specification to describe the endpoint. There is en-detailed about [OpenAPI decorator in loopbac4 here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_openapi.html#api-decorator).
Now to solve the above issue. lets create:

1. Schema for User Login i.e {"username":string, "password":string}
   in the schema definition you can also add the validation rules.

   ````
   const  UserLoginSchema = {
   type: 'object',
   required: ['email', 'password'],
   properties: {
     username: {
       type: 'string',
     },
     password: {
       type: 'string',
     },
   },
   }; ```
   ````
2. Now lets quickly create your RequestBody c'tor for login. Remember as per OpenApi Specification the request body would contain description, required and content.

```
 export const UserLoginRequestBody = {
      description: 'Required input for login',
      required: true,
      content: {
        'application/json': {schema: UserLoginSchema},
      },
    };
```

3. Now you are ready to use your request body.

```
  async login(
    @requestBody(UserLoginRequestBody) credentials: Credentials,
  ): Promise<{token: string}> {
..restCode
```

Thats get you done.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Madaky. After reading your answer I just directly added the differents object directly in my route to not make extras files (i don't know if its a good practice) but it works.

There is the final code with the information added inside the "@requestBody" function:

```js
  @post('/users/login', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'Token',
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
              properties: {
                token: {
                  type: 'string'
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
  async login(
    //here above inside @requestBody
    @requestBody(
      {
        description: 'Required input for login',
        required: true,
        content: {
          'application/json': {
            schema: {
              type: 'object',
              required: ['email', 'password'],
              properties: {
                username: {
                  type: 'string',
                },
                password: {
                  type: 'string',
                },
              },
            },
          }
        },
      }
    ) credentials: Credentials,
  ): Promise<{token: string}> {
    // make sure user exist,password should be valid
    const user = await this.userService.verifyCredentials(credentials);
    // console.log(user);
    const userProfile = await this.userService.convertToUserProfile(user);
    // console.log(userProfile);

    const token = await this.jwtService.generateToken(userProfile);
    return Promise.resolve({token: token})
  }
```

It's working like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Good to Hear. Carry on. To make the work isolated you can use the code in different files. which are easier to track for later revisions